# Best pattern to check conditions and show related messages in a ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 project including following parts:

**Index View**

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLogic.Process>
@*do something ...*@
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(int processId)
{           
    return View(Fac.GetChildrenProcess(processId));
}
```

**Facade class**

```
public List<Process> GetChildrenProcess (int processId)
{
    Process process = new ProcessContoller().GetInfo(processId);
    if (process == null)
      return null;
    List<Process> children = new ProcessContoller().GetListByParentId(processId);
    return children;
}
```

**ShowMessage**

```
private ActionResult ShowMessage(string messageText, DisplayMessageType messageType)
{
    ViewBag.CssClass = messageType.ToString();
    ViewBag.MessageContent = messageText;
    return PartialView("_ShowMessage");
}
```

According to follow [SOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/architectural-principles#separation-of-concerns) pattern, I tent to check if condition `if (process == null)` in a class like `Facade` not in my controller (`Index action`).

But I cope with a problem to show message to user in best pattern. For example if `processId` is invalid in action, `if (process == null)` is true and I should show a message like `Selected process is invalid`. To show a message, I have a `Partial view` like `_ShowMessage`.

> - I can't check the condition `if (process == null)` in my controller    because of following SOC pattern.
> - I can't show my message in `Facade` because is a class not       a controller.
> - I can't return some Boolean value from `GetChildrenProcess` because      it should return a List.
> - I can pass a Boolean value by `ref` or `out` and `if (process == null)` is    false, I show my message. (I think it's a bad pattern)

So, I am curies about best pattern for checking a condition that is similar to validation and showing a message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could throw an exception in Facade to report the problem to the caller or change `GetChildrenProcess` to return bool with the list as an `out` parameter `bool GetChildrenProcess(int processId, out IList<Process> processes)`

Comment: @qujck Thanks for your comment. `if (process == null)` isn't an error and I think throw an exception is a correct way. `GetChildrenProcess` is responsible for returning a list and I think changing the return value isn't proper choice as well.

Comment: Is the processId an arbitrary value entered by a user, or is it coming from some list of possible process id's. In the first case input validation is needed, in the second there is an error in the flow and an exception is in its place.

Comment: @Glenner003 `processId` in action is taken from query string and after that it is passed to `GetChildrenProcess` as a parameter. As I said, `if (process == null)` is true, a invalid message should be shown and it isn't an error to throw an exception.